# issue while installing esp idf toolchain on raspbian linux

Tags: raspbian, esp-idf

I was installing the esp idf toolchain on my raspberry pi 4b running raspbian linux using the [getting started guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v4.2/esp32/get-started/index.html#get-started-get-esp-idf)

I am having a problem at [step 3](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v4.2/esp32/get-started/index.html#step-3-set-up-the-tools).

when I enter the following command:

```
cd ~/esp/esp-idf
./install.sh esp32
```

it returns me:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ~/esp/esp-idf
./install.sh esp32
bash: cd: /home/pi/esp/esp-idf: No such file or directory
bash: ./install.sh: No such file or directory
```

Please provide a straightforward solution for this problem.

I also tried other commands listed in the guide but it returned the same/similar output.

Comment: Look back on what happened in Step 2, which is where you should have downloaded the stuff

Comment: @JamesZ already did that and it successfully downloaded the stuff. Step 3 is not working however.

Comment: The error says that the directory does not exist, so either that was not successful, or you've downloaded it into a different directory.